# VB6 to VB.net porting

Tags: vb.net, vb6

I am porting a VB6 project to VB.net and i am getting this error `"'Sorted' is not a member of 'System.Windows.Forms.ListView'"`

```
System.Windows.Forms.SortOrder.Ascending
            .Sort()
            'UPGRADE_ISSUE: MSComctlLib.ListView property lswFloorAll_F.Sorted was not upgraded. Click for more: 'ms-help://MS.VSCC.v90/dv_commoner/local/redirect.htm?keyword="076C26E5-B7A9-4E77-B69C-B4448DF39E58"'
            .Sorted = False
```

Answer (score 5):

In vb.net, there is no "`.sorted`" for a listview. You can use the .Sorting property instead, and optionally make a ListViewItemSorter property to specify a comparer class. It's a lot messier in vb.net.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.sorting%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.listviewitemsorter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx